# Playbook variables in config

Tags: variables, ansible, global-variables

I would like to pass a variable to any playbook on a particular system. Currently this is done on the command line:

```
amos@sandbox $ ansible-playbook -e 'working_env=sandbox' playbooks/foo.yml
```

the working_env variable will determine things like what users go on systems in that environment. Each of the systems we use to launch playbooks have an environment variable set for everyone in /etc/profile.

```
amos@sandbox $ echo $WORKING_ENV
sandbox
```

I would like to use the value of that variable to populate the "working_env" variable for ansible. We lack a static inventory file, as the hosts are autoscaling and wandering around in name and number. As such I can't include it in the inventory with ease, though I would be interested if this could be done for all hosts in a static inventory file, I didn't find any reference to something like [all:vars] for an ansible inventory, and it and some variations didn't function. We do have a static ansible.cfg file, could a playbook variable be introduced here?

My goal is to have:

```
amos@sandbox $ ansible-playbook playbooks/foo.yml
```

run the same as the first example, saving us from entry errors on the variable assignment.

The best that I've found is setting:

```
vars:
  working_env:  "{{ lookup('env','WORKING_ENV') }}"
```

in each playbook, but there are quite a few playbooks, and the continuous repetition lacks elegance. Leaving me with hope there is a better way.

Comment: Have you looked at group vars (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)? If your dynamic inventory uses known or predictable host groups, then you could add your vars into files like `group_vars/test` and `group_vars/prod`, and yes - `group_vars/all` works too

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:
Create a file `all` under **/etc/ansible/group_vars**

`cat /etc/ansible/group_vars/all`

> working_env:  "{{ lookup('env','WORKING_ENV') }}"